# How to load a B+ tree index file to memory if it doesn’t already exist?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, b-tree

As shown in the figure,C1–0 is’t in memory,C1 in memory, but not record C1–0 physical address,should I record it in C1?

[figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PakTS.png)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not load entire tables or indexes into memory.  It loads *blocks* on demand and bumps them out on roughly a "least recently used" algorithm.

Loading entire indexes is not possible if you do not have enough RAM.  The "caching" of blocks works regardless of the size.